# Kendo TreeView with remote datasource only populates the root elements

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am having difficulty in fully populating a Kendo TreeView with a remote datasource, although with a local datasource it works fine.

In short, the first sample below uses a local datasource. This all works perfectly:

```js
// local datasource, works perfectly
var local = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [
        {
            "DeviceGroupId": 1,
            "DeviceGroupName": "Superdeluxe Devices",
            "Devices": [
                {
                    "Id": 1000,
                    "Name": "My First Device"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 1001,
                    "Name": "My Second Device"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    schema: {
        model: {
            children: "Devices"
        }
    }
});

// initialize - this works!
$("#list-of-devices").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: local,
    dataTextField: ["DeviceGroupName", "Name"],
    loadOnDemand: false
});
```

Again, the sample above works just fine. Now, the second sample below does not: it only populates the treeview's root element ("Superdeluxe Devices"). And it totally ignores the children.

```js
// remote datasource
var remote = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/api/devices/list", // <-- confirmed this works
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                children: "Devices"
            }
        }
    }
});

// initialize
$("#list-of-devices").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: remote, // the issue: only shows top level nodes
    dataTextField: ["DeviceGroupName", "Name"],
    loadOnDemand: false
});
```

So, the issue in the second sample is that **only the top level nodes** are shown, without any option to expand.

I have looked into the following:

- The data in both datasources, local and remote, are identical (I copied the results from remote into local)
- Enabled/disabling the `loadOnDemand` option, [now setting it by default to 'false'](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#configuration-loadOnDemand)
- Mapping stuff through the schema.data and schema.parse functions to no effect
- Looked into the both the [HierarchicalDataSource API](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/hierarchicaldatasource) and the [TreeView API](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview), as well as the [Binding to remote data demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/remote-data-binding)
- Looked into [older UserVoice issue](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/3072947-treeview-allow-hierarchicaldatasource-to-be-fully-), which indicates that it's possible now to fully load and render a TreeView

Summarized, I can't seem to figure out why the local variant works perfectly - and the remote does not show the children. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your remote DataSource definition where you defined the `schema.model` as part of the transport and it is not. It should be:

```
var remote = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "list.json",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            children: "Devices"
        }
    }
});
```

`schema` is at the same level than `transport`.

Comment: Ah, I've totally blind stared on that one. This was indeed the problem.